# How to fetch data from API based on params in the URL

Tags: react-native, react-redux, axios

I'm building an app in React Native fetching data from an API. 
The API data is information about flights departures/arrivals. 
What I'm trying to do is very simple, I want that the app has 2 tabs which switch screens between Arrivals and Departure. The 2 screens will show all the flights departures or arrivals. 
At the moment I did the app only to show the departures flights and getting data from the URL like `URL/flights/departures`. What I cannot understand as I'm new in Native is how can I fetch data based on the URL params. What I mean is that I have the API URL and I would like to fetch the data if it is departures or arrivals adding to the URL like `API/flights/{flightType}` so when a screen changes the correct data is fetched. What I did for now is below but only for departures and I would like to understand how to change it to do as I need.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { apiBaseURL } from "../Utils/Constants";
import {
    FETCHING_FLIGHTS_DATA
    ,FETCHING_FLIGHTS_DATA_SUCCESS,
    FETCHING_FLIGHTS_DATA_FAIL
} from "../Utils/ActionTypes";

export default function FetchFlightData() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: FETCHING_FLIGHTS_DATA});
        return axios.get(`${apiBaseURL}/departures`)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch({ type: FETCHING_FLIGHTS_DATA_SUCCESS, payload: res.data})
            })
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch({ type: FETCHING_FLIGHTS_DATA_FAIL, payload: err.data})
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to aceive? Are you getting the expected response from the api endpoint? You want to render the flights? what?

Comment: @Shivam I want to fetch flights data from this two endpoints URL/flights/departures and URL/flights/arrivals when I switch screen pressing the tab. To be clear when I press the tab for departures I should fetch departures and when press arrivals fetch for arrivals. So what I need is how to add params to the URL to fetch data based on flights type.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the flight type as a parameter to your function and when switching the tab call the `FetchFlightData` with the right type. You probably should separate the fetch success for each type or add the flight type as a parameter to your payload and then in the reducer make the difference between data of departures or data of arrivals

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { apiBaseURL } from "../Utils/Constants";
import {
   FETCHING_FLIGHTS_DATA,
   FETCHING_FLIGHTS_DATA_SUCCESS,
   FETCHING_FLIGHTS_DATA_FAIL
} from "../Utils/ActionTypes";

export default function FetchFlightData(flightType) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: FETCHING_FLIGHTS_DATA});
        return axios.get(`${apiBaseURL}/${flightType}`)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch({ type: FETCHING_FLIGHTS_DATA_SUCCESS, payload: {data:res.data,type:flightType}})
            })
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch({ type: FETCHING_FLIGHTS_DATA_FAIL, payload: err.data})
            })
    }
}

//somewhere in the reducer
case FETCHING_FLIGHTS_DATA_SUCCESS:
  return {
     ...state,
     arrivals: action.payload.type === 'arrival' ? action.payload.data: state.arrivals,
     departures: action.payload.type === 'departures' ? action.payload.data:state.departures
  }
break;

// somewhere in your code when you detect a change of tab
FetchFlightData('arrivals');
FetchFlightData('departures');
```

Comment: I did the changes but get this error: TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...flight.data.map...') 
here https://pastebin.com/gtR1brsQ